# PHP $_REQUEST Sometime empty

Tags: php, request, intermittent

`$_REQUEST` is coming empty sometimes even though log says that `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` is non zero.

Below is some of the information from `$_SERVER`:

```
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BTRS125268; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; AskTbARS/5.17.0.25589)
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 180
```

Comment: show us your code from client and from server

Comment: you want to check if response is coming or not ?? correct ??

Comment: By the way no wounder that you have trouble: You use the IE, in a old version and than with spyware. OMG!

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the problem is that you post a variable e.g. test and that you have the same variable as parameter in the url. So your `$_POST['test']` variable will be overridden by `$_GET['test']` and you have the empty value of `$_GET['test']` in `$_REQUEST['test']`.

So better use directly `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is an associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.
Whereas `$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. `$_REQUEST` is a subset of `$_SERVER`, so it is obvious that though `$_REQUEST` is empty the `$_SERVER` is having some content.